# Selector for `error` value, when throw SubmissionError _error

Tags: redux-form

I am trying to get the `error` prop of a form. When a form throws `throw new SubmissionError({ _error:'hi' })` the `this.props.error` value is set to `"hi"`. However I tried all the selectors here - https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/docs/api/selectors.md/

I expected `getFormSubmitErrors` to give me the `error` prop, but it doesn't. Is there a way to get this? I even tried: `getFormSyncErrors`, `getFormAsyncErrors`, `getFormSubmitErrors`, `getFormSyncWarnings`, `getFormMeta`.

I am using v7.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the awesome folks in the `redux-form` contributor community, they add a selector `getFormError` - https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/pull/3483 it is available in [v7.1.0](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/releases/tag/v7.1.0)